# Is there any way concatenate the variable name with a string or it is basic programming Mistake

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on an AngularJs app. I have an array of HTML select tags where I am concatenating the ng-model name and the options list name with a variable. He re I have two list or arrays. the first array is a levels list which is used to append multiple select tags on the document.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="level in levelslist">
<select ng-model="subtopics_"+{[{level}]} ng-options="subtopic.name for subtopic  in subtopicslist_"{[{level}]} ng-change="loadOtherSubTopics(level)">
</select>
</div>
```

as seeing in the HTML code, i am concatenating the level with the array name and the model name. and calling a function on ng-change. which is an AJAX request.
my AngularJs functions is

```
$scope.loadSubTopics=function(){
        $http.get('/pathfortherequest/).
            success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.subtopicslist_+data.level=data.subtopicslist;
            })
            .
            error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;        
            });
       };
```

i have a level variable in the data return by the backend. what i want to do is as i have lists and ng-models names concatenated with the level variable. while assigning the data to that list, i want to concatenate the list name with the data.level  recieved from the ajax request as

```
$scope.subtopicslist_+data.level=data.subtopicslist;
```

but when i m trying to do it , there is an error that

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
$scope.subtopicslist_+data.level=data.subtopicslist;
```

and i am trying to concatenate the name of the list or array . Tell me how can i do this.
like as in python we can do this using %s %(level). how can we apply same in AngularJs?
help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although possible, I suspect concatenating variable names isn't what you need here. You can use an object to achieve what you need. In the controller you can define it to be an object:

```
$scope.subtopicslist = {};
```

And then on $http success, you can assign properties by "level"

```
$scope.subtopicslist[data.level] = data.subtopicslist;
```

And then in the template you can still use a single element of this object as a model

```
ng-model="subtopicslist[level]"
```

Comment: thanx , but what i did is i concatenate the array name with the level value. there are multiple subtopics list which has their own subtopics. I am doing this in a recursive way

Comment: I don't think what I posted means you can't do that. The "level" variable can be any string. Say, "home_office_chairs". Although I would say it's usual to use multidimensional arrays/objects for this, like subtopicslist["home"]["office"]["chairs"].

Comment: Yes, I am Trying this. the same solution you told me, thanx

Comment: Yeah, It works for me. thankyou. now in HTML i used 
<div data-ng-repeat="level in levelslist">
<select ng-model="subtopics_"+{[{level}]} ng-options="subtopic.name for subtopic  in subtopicslist[{[{level}]}]" ng-change= "loadOtherSubTopics(level)" >
</select>
</div> 
means just assing the index to the subtopicslist and changed the js code as u suggested. Thank you

Comment: It surprises me that ng-model="subtopics_"+{[{level}]} works as you expect to be honest, as I would think everything after the closing " would be ignored by the ngModel directive.

Comment: That ng-model i didn't check. I checked till the list. means the values a assigned to the list has been assigned. and i think there may be same problem with ng-model because concatenation with the variables.

Comment: Yes, as u said and i expected, the same problem. Cannot concatinate variables .

Comment: I did this by giving name ng-model="subtopics"  and then passing the complete element to the function on ng-change=loadmoresubtopics(subtopics). this has solved my problem. but i assigned the array index to the ng-model it produces a syntex error